# Alternating Audio Waves

Tags: wordplay, cipher, language

Try solving this cipher from these strange memos:

Memo 1

> Welcome Comet, today's Thisbe plus Russell here!

Memo 2

> Reading outlaws loudness.

Memo 3

> Retro memo: Berlin today upheld voting thesis, "Putin Salutes". Thanks be to God. U

P.S. The same algorithm is used on all memos

Enjoy ;)

---

Hint:

1

> This is the largest evidence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gimmick

> The title offers a fairly large hint: "Alternating Audio Waves" suggests that this could be a pronunciation puzzle. But what could alternating mean? Perhaps we should take every other syllable in each word.

Translation

> Memo 1: Welcome Comet, today's Thisbe plus Russell here!
>  Wel-come Com-et, to-days, this-bee, plus, rus-sell, here
>  Taking every other syllable gives: "Wel-com-to-this-plus-sell" which approximately sounds like "Welcome to this puzzle".
>
>  Memo 2: Reading outlaws loudness.
>  Read-ing out-laws loud-ness
>  Every other syllable gives "Read out loud"
>
>  Memo 3: Retro memo: Berlin today upheld voting thesis, "Putin Salutes". Thanks be to God. U
>  Re-tro mem-oh Ber-lin to-day up-held vot-ing the-sis pu-tin sal-utes thanks be to god u
>  Every other syllable gives "Re-mem-ber to up-vot the pu-sal thanks to u" or "Remember to upvote the puzzle, thanks to you"

I'm not sure what the hint means though.

Comment: Nailed it, nice job! +1 +tick