# PSE x Wiki x World: How can it be?

Tags: cipher

The following is a encoded first line from a Wikipedia page. Your task is to decipher it. Enjoy!

> 239#**27**#682 **372**#**52**#41#599#995 354 **856** 227#886#**244**#**82**#**94** **252**#**681** **672**#**61**#**32**#239#246#**673**-*376*-599#*46*#**597** (**672**&**387**) **250**#**46**#1-242#39#34 **244**#**673** 676#**81**#**386**#**248**#**211** 91 **235**#**350**#58#381#**262** ___#**32**#**48**#**376**#**1-684**

Bonus: Fill in the blank with a 3-digit number!

Hint/ Clarification:

1

> I left out a tag since it would be a big hint for the cipher

2

> Formatting matters

3

> The sentence have not ended because it is too long... but this is already a legitimate sentence (i.e. grammatical)

4

> I am sure that you all know what this wiki page is describing

---

Another cipher of mine, enjoy!

> [Cipher 001: Strange Memos](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77749/cipher-001-strange-memos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decoded text reads:

> "Stack Exchange is a network of question-and-answer (Q&A) websites on topics in diverse fields ..."   It is taken from the Wikipedia page on [Stack Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange).

Cracking the code:

> General observations: The code has a lot of two- and three-digit numbers. The only single-digit number is 1. These numbers are formatted: Many are bold; fewer are plain and two (*376* and *46*) are in italics.
>
>  There are spaces, hash marks and some punctuation. I think it is safe to assume that the hash marks concatenate letters, which are represented by the numbers, and that all other symbols represent themselves.
>
>  The code is best reverse-engineered from the plain text. We don't have it, but the fourth hint suggests that the Wiki page isn't a huge surprise. One of the obvious candidates is the Wiki on Stack Exchange and it looks good: The combo (**672**&**387**) is very likely the "(Q&A)" from the page and the block with two hyphens before that could be "question-and-answer".
>
>  Now align the chunks to the words in the text:
>
> ```
>                                           239 (27) 682   Stack
>                                  (372) (52) 41 599 995   Exchange
>                                                    354   is
>                                                  (856)   a
>                                227 886 (244) (82) (94)   network
>                                            (252) (681)   of
> (672) (61) (32) 239 246 (673) - <376> - 599 <46> (597)   question-and-answer
>                                        ((672) & (387))   (Q&A)
>                                 (250) (46) 1-242 39 34   websites
>                                            (244) (673)   on
>                             676 (81) (386) (248) (211)   topics
>                                                     91   in
>                               (235) (350) 58 381 (262)   diverse
>                          ___ (32) (48) (376) (1)-(684)   fields
> ```
>
> Here, numbers in parentheses are bold, numbers in angular brackets are in italics. It is onvious that there isn't a one-to one correspondence of numbers to letters.
>
>  Looking at the short words, we can see that a bold number seems to encode a single letter and a plain number two letters. The italic number *376* between the hyphens could encode "and".
>
>  There are few repeated numbers in the code. The bold **244**, **672** and **673** could encode the letters o, q and n. The plain 239 and 599 seem to encode the letter pairs "st" and "an".
>
>  Let's assign the rest of the letters. That kinda works, but there are problems with additional hyphens. Anyway, we have: swe = 46; ch = 41; it  = 39; es = 34. That rings a bell*: These are [telephone prefixes for countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes): +46 is Sweden, +41 is Switzerland and so on. That also explains the extra hyphens, which always occur after a 1: These are four-digit codes of th North American region that all begin with a 1.
>
>  So the code is: A number in italics encodes the [three-letter ISO code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) of the country whose prefix the number is. A plain number encodes the [two-letter ISO code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) of that country and a bold number encodes the second letter of the two-letter code. (The second letter code allows to encode rare letters like X and Q.)
>
>  ________
>  * New-year's resolution: Lay off the puns.

And the bonus?

> The blank must encode FI, which is the two-letter code for Finland, whose calling code is +358. So the blank must be a plain "358".

Comment: well done, sorry my bad for bonus, edited!

Comment: Let's pretend that didn't happen. `:)` **233** # **27** # **977** # 595 / 227 # **263** / 967 # 54!